# Transfering file over a socket in ftp protocol

Tags: java, sockets, ftp, serversocket

I have a problem to send a file(not necessarily a txt file) over a socket.I have 2 classes:Server,Client.When I read from a socket output stream and want to write the bytes in a file,it looks working but when i open the file it has nothing.(corrupted showing the size=0 kb).I also want it to transfer all kind of file over a socket.I don't want to use appache commons net.
Here is my code
Server class

```
FileOutputStream toFile1 = new FileOutputStream(f);             
BufferedOutputStream toFile= new BufferedOutputStream(toFile1);
BufferedInputStream bis=new BufferedInputStream(incoming.getInputStream());
byte[]buffer=new byte[2048];
int bytesRead=0;



while((bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)) >= 0)
{   
    toFile.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

}

toFile.close();
toFile1.close();
bis.close();
out.println("226 Connection Closed");
out.flush();
                  }
```

Client class

```
 BufferedOutputStream output = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
 byte[] buffer = new byte[60*2024];
 int bytesRead = 0;
 while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer,0,60*1024)) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way that can happen with that code is if you are sending a zero length file, or maybe reading from a file input stream that is already positioned at EOF, or else you are looking at the wrong file afterwards.

Comment: Thanks all.I must flush & close the output at the end of my client.I have another problem:If in middle of working,client got disconned,what should server do?

Comment: @Proud Close the data connection, abort the operation, and report the error via the command connection. Maybe delete the partial upload, depending on your requirements. If you get an exception writing to the command channel, close that too.